# Error while debugging first app in flutter using a real device

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, vscode-debugger

I'm using VS code without Android studio in Ubuntu 20.04. While running the first app in flutter in debugging mode in an real device produced this error given below. I also tried to change my JDK version but it didn't worked.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Nokia 6 1 Plus in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper    

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 12s                                                     
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        18.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please suggest a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gradle sync has failed for some reason.
Do this

1. File > Open
2. Navigate to your project
3. You will see an android folder there open that as project in a new window
4. Check the gradle sync issues and resolve those